# Can we create custom db role at logical server level in Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a Logical Azure SQL Server that houses multiple Azure SQL databases.

Is it possible to create any custom db role at the logical server level?

Through this role, I want to grant read-only permission on all Azure SQL databases belonging to the logical SQL Server.

Comment: That isn't how an on-premises `LOGIN` would even work. If a `LOGIN` requires access to databases it needs a `USER` in that database (the only exception to that is when the `LOGIN` is a `sysadmin`). As Azure SQL Databases are all contained databases, then you're going to need to create `USER` credentials in all of your databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot do that because [Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) are database-level securables. In addition, in Azure SQL Database, the server is a logical concept and permissions can't be granted on a server level.

Only the permissions that are held by fixed server-level roles can propagate to database permissions.